# Two way binding Firebase – incorrect rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vuefire

I'm using VueFire to bind my data to a Firebase instance. I think at the moment my rules are incorrect.

Here is my database:

[image]

I'm trying to just allow the update of the tv_video variable:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
      "games":{
        "$gameId":{
          "schema":{
            "tv_video" : {
              ".read" : true,
              ".write": true
            }  
          }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Inside of Vue I'm using the below:

```
firebase() {
  return {
    game: {
      source: db.ref("games/" + this.gameId).child("schema"),
      asObject: true,
      // Optional, allows you to handle any errors.
      cancelCallback(err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
  };
},
```

Which is correctly binding a `v-model="game.tv_video"`, but when I update it nothing is changing.

Comment: Just to make sure it is the rules that are not working, you should try running the simulator accessed from the Simulate button in the upper right of the rules editor in the console. You can check and see if the rules you are using are permitting your operations or not.

Comment: If you check the JavaScript console of your browsers, are there any errors?